# Max horizontal momentary load of vertical steel tube

Tags: structural-engineering

I have sections of steel tube I want to set up for use as zip line anchors and was wondering what the allowable load would be on the vertically mounted tubes. I read that a zip line could have momentary tensions of up to 8,000 lbs put on the anchoring structures. The tubes are rolled, welded steel, 0.83 inch wall thickness (14 ga.). The end anchor point I was planning on was 10' long buried 2 feet in the ground in an 18" diameter concrete pier. The anchor point for the line would be 4 inches from the top so 7 ft 8 in. above ground.

The start side anchor post would be the same steel tube but buried 3 feet down in 15" a pier. The anchor point will either be at 9 feet above ground or 15.5 ft. Depending on my ability to brake the trolley. The start side tube will have another one directly behind it at 22" center to center that I could hook up a guy wire between to beef it up since there will obviously be more deflection.

Your thoughts are muchappreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a ['Naive design' question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/188/1832). Such questions are excessively broad and are therefore not a good fit for our format. See if you can [edit] your question to make it specific and answerable.

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree with Wasabi that this is a very broad question, here is the 10,000 ft view of the process

1. Draw a free body diagram of the tube.
2. Solve the equations of static equilibrium to determine the reaction forces and moments on the tube
3. Draw the shear/moment diagram to determine the loads at each point on the tube
4. Determine the stress at the most highly loaded point
5. Compare that to the yield stress for your material
6. apply an appropriate factor of safety

If you are not sure what I mean by some of these, you'll want to pick up a textbook on Statics and a textbook on Strength of Materials (typically these are semester long sophomore level classes for Mechanical Engineering students)

Comment: Ok, I will take an engineering course and solve it myself. Thanks.

Comment: I can't tell if that's a sarcastic comment.  Was only trying to say that you've asked a very broad question, so the best we can give is a very broad answer.  If you can be more specific, we might be able to be more helpful.  E.g., you don't say the diameter of the tube in question. This makes a big difference.  If it's a 1" diameter tube, there's basically no way a 15.5 ft section could support an 8000 lbf side load.  If it's a 12" diameter, then it might work, but we'd have to do some calculations.